# laravel eloquent migrations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In laravel eloquent relationship, is it still necessary to make migration even though there's an existing database? beginners here.

I create a one-to-one eloquent relationship inside my model to get the specific column from another table's record and fetch to the datatable, but it did not work.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Directorystatus extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'user_status';
    protected $fillable = ['status_id' , 'status_xtitle'];

    public function userbasic() {
        return $this->belongsTo(directorybasic::class,'user_xusern','status_xuser');
    }
}

class Directoryuser extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'user_basic';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    protected $fillable = ['user_id' , 'user_xusern' , 'user_xfirtname' ,'user_xmiddlename','user_xlastname'];

    public function userstatus() {
        return $this->hasOne(directorystatus::class,'user_xusern','status_xuser');
    }
}
```

Comment: "*even though there's an existing database*" - OK there's a database, are there any tables in it?  If you already have tables for both models, do those tables already include the foreign keys that reference each other?  Adding a relationship will not automatically alter your table schema to make the relationship work.

Comment: it will not add a new database table?

Comment: No, adding a relationship does not touch your database.  It is up to you to (separately from your models) create migrations that will create your tables, and define the foreign keys which relate those tables.  Models and relationships *describe* the relations that exist in your schema.  If you don't set up the tables and foreign keys the relationships won't work.  Of course you don't need to use migrations to set the schema up, you can just manually create it, but migrations are the Laravel way, and quite handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Migrations are not necessary. Defining relationships on both sides is also not necessary, if you don't need them both. (You can have only belongsTo, without having hasOne or hasMany in the opposite model.)

First, make sure you are using the right object (Directorystatus::class / Directoryuser:class - I see they're not capitalized in your code). The next param is the foreign key, meaning the column which points to a model's primary key. The third param is optional and is used only if the primary key is not `id`.

For example if you have a column status_xuser in the table user_status, which contains a user_id from user_basic table, you should define it like this:

```
public function userbasic() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Directoryuser::class,'status_xuser','user_id');
}
```

And in order to use this relationship, when you retrieve a model from the db, for example, you should call on it the same way your relationship function is named.

```
$status = Directorystatus::find(1);
$user = $status->userbasic();
```

I would also suggest you name your classes in camelCase, because it's the accepted practice (in Laravel especially).